# Finding rows that satisfy some date constraints existing in a table

Tags: mysql, date, select

I have a table like this

```
CustomerId     serviceID             from                           To
id1           serv1          '2016-01-01 07:22:33'       '2016-01-05 07:22:33'
id1           serv1          '2016-02-21 08:30:10'       '2016-02-27 08:30:10'
id1           serv2          '2016-02-15 18:30:10'       '2016-02-15 19:30:10'
id1           serv3          '2016-02-19 18:30:10'       '2016-02-19 19:30:10'
id1           serv4          '2017-01-01 08:30:10'       '2017-01-01 09:00:10'
```

where:

```
 serv1 = "in Dog Hospital"
 serv2 = "X ray service"
 serv3 = "Recovering meal"
```

For a report, I need to find all those rows that imply the "dog" took that service while in the "Dog hospital" i.e. those services taken during the dates the dog was at the "dog hospital". 
Any suggestions, please?

Comment: `where serviceId = 'serv1'` ??

Comment: no, no... A dog could be using another service while staying at the hospital. i.e. while using serv1

Comment: For a dog, I need to find those services that happened while he was at the hospital...

Comment: Do you have a PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: let's assume that there is one field called 'Row ID' as primary key

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that the desired query would return no rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for the rows than fall in serv1's period like this:

```
select *
from t a
where exists (
    select 1
    from t b
    where serviceId = 'serv1'
    and a.`from` >= b.`from`
    and a.`to` <= b.`to`
);
```

#### [Demo @ SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b5a3f/1)